# Detector vs mixer

Tags: experimental-physics

I'd like to measure the power of an incoming laser beam, which could be modulated to carry a signal. My laser will be in the range of 100um to 200um. So I think a Schottky diode detection system would suit me best, but manufacturers distinguish between mixers and detectors. What is the difference between a mixer and a detector? Are both "square law detectors" (ie they measure the square of the E-field, ie power)?

Comment: Can you give an example of some devices which the manufacturer's refer to as "mixer" and "detector"?

Comment: For example, Virginia diodes: http://vadiodes.com/index.php/en/products/mixers vs http://vadiodes.com/index.php/en/products/detectors

Comment: Is the laser phase or amplitude modulated?

Comment: I'm still trying to decide. Does one or the other work better for a mixer or detector?

Comment: I have no idea, unfortunately. I work with microwave signals but I'm no optics expert. I was just trying to get all the particulars out in the open in case someone else who can help you reads this post.

Comment: Do you really want a measurement of power, or do you just want to be able to detect modulation?  I don't think you want a mixer unless you are doing heterodyne detection or something like that.  Besides, the mixers on the page you link don't operate in the terahertz region.

Comment: Definitely heterodyne detection. I think I figured out that a mixer is what I want.